# Why for loop returning last value alone instead of all other values in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have function something below,

```js
function test(){
    const obj = {}
    const arr = []

    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        obj.i = i
        arr.push(obj)
    }

    return arr
} 

const res = test();
console.log(res);
```

which returns

```
[{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99},{"i":99}]
```

but why it not return

```
[{"i":0},{"i":1},...,{"i":99}]
```

any reason.

Comment: All of them are *references* to the same underlying object.

Comment: Because the you push the reference to the initial object, not a new object.

Comment: Because you keep referring to the same object. You can fix it by creating the object inside the loop.

Comment: `Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => ({ i: i+1 }))`

Comment: It is happening because of call by reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the value each time it is looping.Do like this

```
function test(){
     const arr = []
     for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         const obj = {}
        obj.i = i
        arr.push(obj)
     }

    return arr
} 

const res = test();
console.log(res);
```